# How can increment a sequence only once on a bulk insert?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given a model like this:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model'
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, index=True)
    value = Column(Numeric, doc='value')
    batch = Column(Integer, Sequence('my_model_batch_seq'), doc='Batch ID of the update')
```

I want to issue a batch insert that adds all the new objects with the same `batch` ID. The code below increments for each object which is not what I'm looking for.

```
objects = [
    MyModel(
        value=x,
    ) for x in range(10)
]
db.bulk_save_objects(objects)
```

Comment: Explicitly select nextval first and pass it along with the new objects? As an aside `nullable=False` and `index=True` are redundant on a primary key column.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a better (sqlalchemy) way to do that than `batch = db.execute("SELECT NEXTVAL('my_model_batch_seq');").first().nextval`?

Comment: `db.query(func.nextval('my_model_batch_seq')).scalar()`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you could first select the next value explicitly:

```
# Note that this may fail, if you haven't configured a bind on
# your Session.
batch = db.query(func.nextval('my_model_batch_seq')).scalar()
```

and then just pass it along:

```
objects = [
    MyModel(
        value=x,
        batch=batch,
    ) for x in range(10)
]
db.bulk_save_objects(objects)
```